# opencv VideoCapture very slow with high resolution videos

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I am trying to read a high resolution video using OpenCV VideoCapture and it seems to be extremely slow. I read somewhere changing the buffer sizes might help, but I tried setting all kinds of buffer sizes and its still slow.
Any help here on what settings can help improve reading high resolution videos for java opencv is really appreciated

I am using VideoCapture to read a video from disk. I am using Mac OSX. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
while(camera.read(frame))
{
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = MatToBufferedImage(frame);
    BufferedImage scaledImage = (BufferedImage)getScaledImage(bufferedImage, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);
    publish(icon);

}
```

I am using swingworker and doing this in the background thread.
I am not explicitly setting any openCV properties. Should I be setting any explicit properties is something I am not sure of.

Here is what I observe: My video starts off well and then around 50th frame or so, i see some lag and then again at around 120th frame and it almost completely stops at frame number 190ish.

Comment: A few additional details might help: what camera are you using? What OS is this on? What do you mean by "extremely slow" - can you give us a frames/sec number?

Comment: If an otherwise happy application slows to a crawl it is very likely because it is leaking memory - i.e. allocating more and more memory without freeing or releasing it. I don't see any freeing if memory in your loop - though I am no Java programmer. Try running macOS's `Activity Monitor` while your code runs and watching the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resizing the individual frames?

```
while(camera.read(frame))
{
resize(frame,frame,Size(640,360));
imshow("frame",frame);
}
```